# Combine Retry, Curcuit breaker and delayed scheduled delivery

Tags: masstransit

I am struggling hard to properly test this scenario and could not really match the numbers. Could you please verify whether this configuration is correct for the below scenario?

When the message comes to consumer first time, want to retry for these exceptions  WebException, HttpRequestException, RequestTimeoutException, TimeoutException. And after this retries exhausted I want to redeliver these messages( only for the above exceptions) using delayed exchange with intervals first time delay 2 minutes, then 4 minutes and finally 6 minutes and after 3 times stop redeliver and push to _error queue.

I want UseMessageRetry() should execute only first time and not every time when the message get to consumer through delayed exchange.

```
cfg.UseDelayedExchangeMessageScheduler();
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(rabbitMqConfig.QueueName, e =>
{
e.PrefetchCount = 20;
e.UseRateLimit(100, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
e.UseDelayedRedelivery(p =>
{
p.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4),TimeSpan.FromMinutes(6));
});
e.UseCircuitBreaker(cb =>
{
cb.TrackingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
cb.TripThreshold = 15;
cb.ActiveThreshold = 10;
cb.ResetInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
});
e.UseMessageRetry(r =>
{
r.Incremental(2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));
r.Handle<WebException>();
r.Handle<HttpRequestException>();
r.Handle<TimeoutException>();
r.Handle<RequestTimeoutException>();
});
e.Consumer<Consumers.ProductConsumer>(provider);
});
```

Comment: FIRST: It's `e.UseScheduledRedelivery`, you're using a deprecated function.

Comment: The filters are nested, and there isn't a way to check in the `UseMessageRetry` conditions if `GetRedeliveryCount` is > 0, since the conditions don't have access to the `ConsumeContext`. I've added [an issue](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/2049) to track this as a possible enhancement:

Comment: Hi Chris, What is the relation between these events in the pipeline?

Is my undesrstandng correct in this case that redeliver and circuit breaker happens only for those exceptions handled in MessageRetry()?
And also in the documentation i have seen UseMessageRetry() has combination of handle and ignore. why do we need to specify both? if one exception is handled that means all other are ignored right?

Comment: They're exclusive, if you handle specific ones, that's great. If you exclude specific ones, that's great too. If you specify nothing all are handled. And the redelivery and circuit breaker have their own scope, they don't know anything about UseMessageRetry.

Comment: Ok I see. If I want to handle message retry, circuit breaker and schedule re delivery for WebException, HttpRequestException, TimeoutException and RequestTimeoutException then do I need to specify Handle<> for these exception in all the 3 scopes(retry, circuit breaker and redelivery?

Comment: Yes, otherwise they'll catch all exceptions.