# MassTransit RabbitMQ delay exchange plugin with UseMessageRetry, UseDelayedRedelivery and Consume Fault message in .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

We have used MassTransit with RabbitMQ broker. We need highly fault tolerate service with some additional features.

1. We want to handle the Trasient failures.
2. We want to delay a message and do retry for custom result based response.
3. If still any failure occurred then it has to handled with Fault consumer.
   Considering all above these requirements, Is MassTransit will fit to our solution and allows us to cover all over needs?

Because I have already tried but having some problems as below,

1. The retry is not happening for longer delayes. Even though pugin exist to the RabbitMQ server.
2. The Fault message not consumes. Then tried specifying the queue name but it's moves to skipped queue.

Language: C#, .Net 6
Plugin details: MassTransit & MassTransit.RabbitMQ, version = 8.0.6

Comment: This solution already been tried but not completely a our solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63899476/combine-retry-curcuit-breaker-and-delayed-scheduled-delivery

Comment: I don't see how anyone can assist you without seeing a complete example that shows what you're trying to accomplish. I suggest using a tool like Docker Compose to provide *everything* needed to demonstrate what you are trying. This repo may be a good starting point for you - https://github.com/lukebakken/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-1060

Comment: This article(https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/4-approaches-on-how-to-create-reliable-messaging-architecture-4aefcfc13cfd) has helped me to overcome from problem. And I do understand now, Fault message can be consumed just as notification. The FaultConsumer can't purge those messages after reading from the queue.